# haskell: specialize a function for certain type(s)

Tags: haskell

Say, just an example, I want to implement something like:

```
someWrite ::         IORef a -> a -> IO ()
someWrite = writeIORef

someWrite :: Eq a => IORef a -> a -> IO ()
someWrite ref value = do
    oldValue <- readIORef ref
    if oldValue == value
        then putStrLn "Did not write"
        else writeIORef ref value
```

Obviously the code is illegal. How can something like this be done?

Comment: You write two functions. After all, any usage of the function would lead to the same problem. There is no extension at the moment that provides this kind of behaviour. Also, I can see how this get ambiguous very fast: `foo :: a -> a -> Bool` vs `foo :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` vs `foo :: Enum a => a -> a -> a`. Which one should get used for `foo 1 (2 :: Int)`?

Comment: are you talking about *overloading* of function names here?

Comment: @Zeta  I would expect it select the implementations according to the order. (Like how pattern matching works)

Comment: Pattern matching is a _local property_, but function names bind on a larger scope. The order of functions would then be part of the export, which needs a complete overhaul of the current import/export system. Have a look at function overloading in other languages, e.g. C++, where ambiguity simply leads to compilation aborts.

Comment: @Zeta So yes, what I was trying to do is to find if there is any extension to do it locally.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, KindSignatures, FunctionalDependencies, UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.IORef

data HTrue
data HFalse

class SomeWrite a where
  someWrite :: IORef a -> a -> IO ()

class SomeWrite' f a where
  someWrite' :: f -> IORef a -> a -> IO ()

instance (Pred f a, SomeWrite' f a) => SomeWrite a where
  someWrite = someWrite' (undefined::f)

class Pred f a | a -> f where {}

instance (f ~ HTrue) => Pred f a
instance Pred HFalse Bool
instance Pred HFalse String
-- Add the rest here

instance SomeWrite' HTrue a where
  someWrite' _ = writeIORef

instance Eq a => SomeWrite' HFalse a where
  someWrite' _ ref value =
    do
      oldValue <- readIORef ref
      if oldValue == value
      then putStrLn "Did not write"
      else writeIORef ref value
```

https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap describes the way to do this.

Comment: where is the `instance` for `Wrapper` without `Eq`? (Hint: it will probably be a duplicate)

Comment: @Carsten Apparently this is possible: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Wait, this is exactly what the OP is asking. :-)

Comment: well yes and no - I think the article describes some of the problems - anyway it might get into an answer if you rewrite it to: a) work b) solves OPs problem (ATM you only linked the article and copy&pasted the introduction from there)

Comment: Will do, as soon as I find time. But there is sample code at the end and obviously it is solving the same problem. I acknowledge that it's just lucky Googling on my part, if you want and I am allowed to, I can convert this to a comment.

Comment: well personally I don't care too much (for me it's a comment but I won't downvote or flag because of it)